# Django - Calling one class method from another in Class Based View

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a method inside a django class based view like called `get_player_stats`. From this method I want to call another method in the same class but I am unable to. Code is like below:

```
class ScoreView(TemplateView):

   def get_player_stats(request):
       player_id = request.GET.get(player_id, None)
       # compute  player stats

       #here I want to call like below:
       self.get_team_stats(player_id)

   def get_team_stats(self, player_id):
      #compute team stats
```

When I run this it says `name 'self' is not defined`

If I try `def get_player_stats(self, request):` it says `missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

If I try `def get_player_stats(request, self):` it says `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

How can I call `get_team_stats` from `get_player_stats`?

This is very frustrating, any help is greatly appreciated

P.S: I call `get_player_stats` as an ajax call by defining a URL path as below:

```
url('score/get_player_stats', views.ScoreView.get_player_stats)
```

Then I call it using $.ajax with `url: '/score/get_player_stats'`

Comment: It is not how you *define* things, it is how you *call* things.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I am very new to django. Can you please help by elaborating a bit?

Comment: Where do you *call* `get_player_stats`? (not `get_team_stats`)?

Comment: I would recommend extracting the `get_player_stats` logic to an external helper module function and then calling that from both views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem   its an ajax call...I defined a URL path as `url('scores/get_player_stats', views.ScoreView.get_player_stats, name='player-stats'),`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then I call it using $.ajax as `url: '/scores/get_player_stats'`

Comment: @UndefinedVariable: I think you use `TemplateView` the wrong way. The idea of a class-based view is that you can declare a `template`, `queryset`, etc. But the idea is that you can *not* simply call an arbitrary function. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see here 2 problems:

1. Misconceptions about `class-based views` in `django`
2. Misconceptions about `object-` and `class-` methods in `python`

Let's look in more detail.

## 1. Django class-based views

It must be sound strange (especially for newcomers) but `class-based view` in django does not means that you bind methods of  `objects`/`classes` to `url`-routes.

More so:

- `django.urls.path` can use only functions of `fn(request, *args, **kwargs)`
- Pythonic `it's better explicite`  for `self`-param  makes `object-methods` unusable for `views` (at least without "special magic").

**So what the meaning of `class-based views`?**

https://github.com/django/django/blob/2bc014750adb093131f77e4c20bc17ba64b75cac/django/views/generic/base.py#L48

In fact it's very simple:

1. `class-based view` expose class method `as_view`
2. `as_view` is a high-order function and not used directly in  `path`/`url` calls.
3. `as_view` constructs actual view function at runtime
4. generated function is not very complicated too. Roughly speaking, it looks for existence of defined `get`/`post`/`put`/`head`-methods, calls them when they exists and raises exceptions when not exists.

So you can see that "one does not simply binds methods of class-view to url-routes in django".

It is a tool that can be hardly recommended for general cases, it works good in cases when this inflexibility is desirable.

## 2. `object-`,`class-`, `static-` methods

OK. Now the second problem.

Can we call from methods of `class-based view` other methods?

Yes we can but with some restrictions.

Let's look at `one-file` demo in django  2.0. (For 1.11 - `%s/path/url/g`)

```
from django.urls import path    
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import classonlymethod


# CASE 1: normal function - OK
def just_a_fun(request, **kwargs):
    context = kwargs if kwargs else {"method": "just a function"}
    return HttpResponse('method = %(method)s' % context)


class ViewClass(object):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return just_a_fun(request, **kwargs)

    # CASE 2: Object method - FAIL, not possible to use in `django.url.path`-calls
    def om_view(self, request):
        return self.get(request, **{"method": "object method"})

    # CASE 3: class method - OK
    @classmethod
    def cm_view(cls, request):
        return cls.get(cls, request, **{"method": "class method"})

    # CASE 4: static method - FAIL, not possible to call `cls.get` or `self.get`
    @staticmethod
    def sm_view(request):
        self = None  # This is a problem with static methods
        return self.get(self, request, **{"method": "static method"})

    # CASE 5: HOF-view, similar to django.views.generic.View.as_view - OK
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        def view(request, **kwargs):
            self = cls(**initkwargs)  # Object construction
            self.request = request
            self.kwargs = kwargs
            return self.get(request, **{"method": "HOF as_view"})

        return view


urlpatterns = [
    path("just-a-fun", just_a_fun),  # OK
    path("object-method",
         ViewClass.om_view),  # Problem: redundant `self` for `path`
    path("class-method", ViewClass.cm_view),  # OK
    path('static-method',
         ViewClass.sm_view),  # Problem: not possible to call `get`
    path('hof-view', ViewClass.as_view()),  # OK. 
]
```

Summary:

1. Plain functions are best in general
2. Object methods are not usable (at least without some "special magic")
3. Class methods: have no problems. But keep in mind that class methods can use only other class methods
4. Static methods: OK for using in `path`/`url` calls but they can't use other methods of classes
5. If you really really want to use OOP:  you can do it in "django way" - create HOFs that will generate actual views functions at runtime. Look at `django.views.generic` source code for inspiration

...

I hope that must clear things up but questions, critique, corrections - you are welcome!

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Comment: @UndefinedVariable Was it helpful as "it answered my puzzle" or "it gave me food for thought"? I'm asking you because I saw a lot of times: django seems for newcomer dead-simple and no-magic till he/she stumbles on `Model`/`Form` `metaclass`-magic