# how to use example not from cmd? is it ready for use?

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to the whole docusign developer code, so I am a bit lost on how to use that properly.

I did install Quickstart.
The example worked for me after installing requirements in the folder of the project and " python3 run.py "

how can I use https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/master/app/eSignature/examples/eg001_embedded_signing.py#L47 without running it from cmd?
Stated differently, are the methods of the class complete to do embedded signing?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have more than simple functions as quickstart, you will be able to check the SDK.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdks/

However, this will be running over the CLI or using Visual Studio as well.

Please let me know if that works.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To use this code directly within your own app, you'll want consolidate the various helper methods and config files located at the top as there's different parts of the example split up for code reuse across the application. Once that's done, use the combined codebase as a reference for making the API calls to both send the envelope and to handle the View request (that's another API call you'll send right after sending the envelope so that you can get a session url that you can direct your end-user to sign.

For the Quickstart application, those different code examples live behind a webform so that when you submit a POST action on the page, it's calling the methods within that embeddedSigning.py, just as you mention.  This python app is a flask application and the routing and logic work within those constraints. I'm not sure what your stack is (Django or perhaps something else?), Though ultimately you'll need to send the envelope and generate a view request thereafter.  Make sure the client user id is included when generating the envelope. To make things easier, we've created a helper method to make the resulting json object that you'll need to send to our API for the envelope.

So, for example, if we took this Django file I borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806626/django-calling-one-class-method-from-another-in-class-based-view):

```
from django.urls import path    
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import classonlymethod


# CASE 1: normal function - OK
def just_a_fun(request, **kwargs):
    context = kwargs if kwargs else {"method": "just a function"}
    return HttpResponse('method = %(method)s' % context)


class ViewClass(object):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return just_a_fun(request, **kwargs)

    # CASE 2: Object method - FAIL, not possible to use in `django.url.path`-calls
    def om_view(self, request):
        return self.get(request, **{"method": "object method"})

    # CASE 3: class method - OK
    @classmethod
    def cm_view(cls, request):
        return cls.get(cls, request, **{"method": "class method"})

    # CASE 4: static method - FAIL, not possible to call `cls.get` or `self.get`
    @staticmethod
    def sm_view(request):
        self = None  # This is a problem with static methods
        return self.get(self, request, **{"method": "static method"})

    # CASE 5: HOF-view, similar to django.views.generic.View.as_view - OK
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        def view(request, **kwargs):
            self = cls(**initkwargs)  # Object construction
            self.request = request
            self.kwargs = kwargs
            return self.get(request, **{"method": "HOF as_view"})

        return view


urlpatterns = [
    path("just-a-fun", just_a_fun),  # OK
    path("object-method",
         ViewClass.om_view),  # Problem: redundant `self` for `path`
    path("class-method", ViewClass.cm_view),  # OK
    path('static-method',
         ViewClass.sm_view),  # Problem: not possible to call `get`
    path('hof-view', ViewClass.as_view()),  # OK. 
]
```

This file is acting like a router for a given route. You could copy the logic from the make_envelope method onto your django object (controller) for your form. Then when someone submits that form, make the `Request.post` action execute the make envelope method, the send_envelope method which sends the POST API call to get your envelopeID, and to finally generate your view request with that given envelope ID and your end-user information (specifically the `client-user-id`) to get that redirectURL that you need to send to start the embedded signing session.

You'll want to also build a callback page to handle the completed requests, whether it's a thanks for signing or a proceed to the next step page, for an ideal user experience.

**DISCLAIMER: I have not tested this and have no idea if it will work.**

I think it might, but you'll need to modify this or perhaps change it to fit your python server stack.  I did my best to present a consolidated file that 'should' do all the steps necessary to generate your redirect url for an embedded signing session with your end-user. Do make sure to include the client-user-id because it will otherwise generate an email and send that instead. You'll need to specify those matching client user ids, the user names, and their emails when generating the view request on an envelopeId. I belive the redirect link is only good for a few minutes to ideally you'll want to generate and redirect immediately:

```
from django.urls import path    
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import classonlymethod
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import base64
from docusign_esign import EnvelopesApi, RecipientViewRequest, Document, Signer, EnvelopeDefinition, SignHere, Tabs, \
    Recipients, ApiClient, AccountsApi

def main(request, **kwargs):
    context = kwargs if kwargs else {"method": "just a function"}
    if request.method == "GET":
       return
    elif request.method == "POST":
        results = embedded_signing(request.body)
        return redirect(results["redirect_url"])


def make_envelope(args):
    """
    Creates envelope
    args -- parameters for the envelope:
    signer_email, signer_name, signer_client_id
    returns an envelope definition
    """

    # document 1 (pdf) has tag /sn1/
    #
    # The envelope has one recipient.
    # recipient 1 - signer
    with open(path.join("path/to/your/documents.pdf"), "rb") as file:
        content_bytes = file.read()
    base64_file_content = base64.b64encode(content_bytes).decode("ascii")

    # Create the document model
    document = Document(  # create the DocuSign document object
        document_base64=base64_file_content,
        name="Example document",  # can be different from actual file name
        file_extension="pdf",  # many different document types are accepted
        document_id=1  # a label used to reference the doc
    )

    # Create the signer recipient model
    signer = Signer(
        # The signer
        email=args["signer_email"],
        name=args["signer_name"],
        recipient_id="1",
        routing_order="1",
        # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
        client_user_id=args["signer_client_id"]
    )

    # Create a sign_here tab (field on the document)
    sign_here = SignHere(
        # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
        anchor_string="/sn1/",
        anchor_units="pixels",
        anchor_y_offset="10",
        anchor_x_offset="20"
    )

    # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tab) to the signer
    # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    signer.tabs = Tabs(sign_here_tabs=[sign_here])

    # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
    envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
        email_subject="Please sign this document sent from the Python SDK",
        documents=[document],
        # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
        recipients=Recipients(signers=[signer]),
        status="sent"  # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
    )

    return envelope_definition
    
def embedded_signing(cls, args):
    envelope_args = args["envelope_args"]
    # 1. Create the envelope request object
    envelope_definition = cls.make_envelope(envelope_args)

    # 2. call Envelopes::create API method
    # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.host = args.base_path
    api_client.set_default_header(header_name="Authorization", header_value=f"Bearer" + args.access_token)
    envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
    envelope_definition = make_envelope(cls, args)
    results = envelope_api.create_envelope(account_id=args["account_id"], envelope_definition=envelope_definition)

    envelope_id = results.envelope_id
    recipient_view_request = RecipientViewRequest(
                authentication_method='None',
                client_user_id=envelope_args["signer_client_id"],
                recipient_id="1",
                return_url=envelope_args["ds_return_url"],
                user_name=envelope_args["signer_name"],
                email=envelope_args["signer_email"]
            )
    # Obtain the recipient_view_url for the embedded signing
    # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
    results = envelope_api.create_recipient_view(
        account_id=args["account_id"],
        envelope_id=envelope_id,
        recipient_view_request=recipient_view_request
    )

    return {"envelope_id": envelope_id, "redirect_url": results.url}
        

class ViewClass(object):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return main(request, **kwargs)

    # CASE 2: Object method - FAIL, not possible to use in `django.url.path`-calls
    def om_view(self, request):
        return self.get(request, **{"method": "object method"})

    # CASE 3: class method - OK
    @classmethod
    def cm_view(cls, request):
        return cls.get(cls, request, **{"method": "class method"})

    # CASE 4: static method - FAIL, not possible to call `cls.get` or `self.get`
    @staticmethod
    def sm_view(request):
        self = None  # This is a problem with static methods
        return self.get(self, request, **{"method": "static method"})

    # CASE 5: HOF-view, similar to django.views.generic.View.as_view - OK
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        def view(request, **kwargs):
            self = cls(**initkwargs)  # Object construction
            self.request = request
            self.kwargs = kwargs
            return self.get(request, **{"method": "HOF as_view"})

        return view


urlpatterns = [
    path("just-a-fun", main),  # OK
    path("send-envelope", ViewClass.get) #embedded signing when this path is called
]
```